# Landscape main window in a xib

Tags: ipad, interface-builder, xcode5, xib

I am creating an iPad app that is landscape only. I have a main window xib but the window is portrait. When the window is selected and I look at the Simulated Metrics the Orientation shows a dimmed (non selectable) option. In deployment Info landscape Left and Landscape Right are selected.  I need landscape so I can design my viewController in landscape.

How can I get the main Window to be in landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, you do not really use a main window xib, but a **storyboard**. In the storyboard you can choose "Landscape" from the "Orientation" menu under "Simulated Metrics" without problem when configuring any view controller.

Comment: Perhaps I do not want to use a storyboard, am I the screwed? Note: this project was started prior to storyboards existed. Also none of the Apple templates are a good starting point for what I need.

Comment: You can substitute your xib with a storyboard just for that one controller (getting the equivalent via `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`). So no, you are not "the screwed". ;-)

Comment: So, Apple decided in their infinite wisdom that when using a zib for an iPad app only portrait is supported. Nice move. An yes I am screwed into using a storyboard. It isn't that I have not used them on other projects, they just don't fit well with this one.

Comment: Interesting Apple-isms: The Single View Application template does not have a CoreData option. Huh?

Comment: I feel your pain. But the answer is still an actionable workaround that solves the problem, so you should accept the answer.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question but it does address the issue, I have used storyboards many times. I think what I will be doing is changing storyboards like xibs.